# What should I do if I put MS Office (e.g. .docx) or OpenOffice( e.g. .odt) document into a git repository?

Tags: git, github

I put several `.docx`, `.txt` and `.pdf` file into a .git repository. I can open, edit, save the local `.docx` file; however, when I push it to github, and download it back to my computer, Word complains that it cannot open it.

In order to store `.docx` file on github, is there some essential steps I should do to the git settings?

Comment: I don't think that this has anything to do with git, but rather with github. If you clone the repository in an other folder, can you open your docx files ?

Comment: Don't store binary data (as `.docx`, `.pdf`) in git. Git is for plain text such as source code, not for binary data!

Comment: @edi9999 Ah, I downloaded the `.docx` file using the `Chrome` browser. After reading your comment, I suspect that maybe it's the broswer's problem. I then `git clone` it to another folder: Word can open it. So it's `Chrome` which cannot play well with github. Thank you very much!

Comment: @musicmatze No, it's not. Git can store any binary data if it's set up properly.

Comment: @NickVolynkin okay, I should have said "git was _meant_ for text"... Of course it can store binary data as well... it just does not make that much sense.

Comment: @Nick Chrome should not have problems with Git or GitHub. Maybe it was the endline issue too.

Comment: you could also try https://github.com/Nicola17/ODT-Git-helper - also there's some tips over at https://web.archive.org/web/20180107081412/https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitTips#How_to_use_git_to_track_OpenDocument_.28OpenOffice.2C_Koffice.29_files.3F

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Solution

Make a `.gitattributes` file in your working directory and add the following line to it:

```
*.docx    binary
```

#### Why not just set `core.autocrlf=false` ?

[This is useful too](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Formatting-and-Whitespace). But configuring `.docx` as a binary format solves not only this problem, but also potential merge issues.

#### What is the origin of this problem?

From http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes , section "Marking files as binary". Note the italicized section.

> Git usually guesses correctly whether a blob contains text or binary data by examining the beginning of the contents. However, sometimes you may want to override its decision, either because a blob contains binary data later in the file, or because the *content, while technically composed of text characters, is opaque to a human reader*.

`.docx` format is a zip folder containting `xml` and binary data, such as images.

Git treated your `.docx` as a text (and not binary) file and replaced endline characters. As Microsoft-developed format, `.docx` is probably using CRLF, which might have been replaced with LF in the remote repository. When you downloaded that file directly from remote, it still had LFs.

In a binary file Git never replaces endline chars, so even the files on remote repository will have proper CRLFs.

#### Applicable formats

This is applicable to any file format which is a zipped package with text and binary data. This includes:

- [OpenDocument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument): `.odt`, `.ods`, `.odp` and others.
- [OpenOffice.org XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice.org_XML): `.sxw`, `.sxc`, `.sxi` and others.
- [Open Packaging Conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Packaging_Conventions) `.docx`, `.xlsx`, `.pptx` and others.

Comment: Thank you. I've added that line in the `.gitattributes` file. But I don't understand that, if the problem is caused by endline characters, why word can open `.docx` file from `git clone` to local folder; while could not open chrome donwnloaded version? They are the same file. Did `git clone` adds `CRLF` back?

Comment: @Nick configuring `.docx` as a binary format solves not only this problem, but also potential merge issues.

Comment: You're right! I tried to download the file from github by first click on the file link, and then *right click* on `View Raw`, `save as...` This time, word could open it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Nick great! Updated my answer according to your approval.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is most likely a GitHub web interface quirk whereby your attempt to download the file actually produced an HTML page about the file. Using clone will, as you found, work fine.